# Find the next and the previous element of each dictionary item

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like as follows:

```
d = {
  1: [‘a’,’b’],
  2: [‘c’,’d’],
  8: [‘l’,’p’],
  12: [‘u’,’v’,’w’,’x’]
}
```

I am iterating through the dictionary using iteritems().how I can find the previous and next item for each item in the dictionary while iterating?

Comment: The `dict` type is not ordered so this won't work. Do you mean OrderedDict?

Comment: Do you mean 'next' and 'previous' as in how the items were originally inserted into the dict, or as in the value of the integer key?  In your example they are the same, but the answer will differ.

Comment: ... or even as in "what order iteritems() returns?"

Comment: You're probably using the wrong data structure for whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: it is a ordered dictionary.for the key value pair 2:[‘c’,’d’] the next item will be 8:[‘l’,’p’] and previous item will be 1:[‘a’,’b']

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, one has to convert keys into a list and rely on the obtained order:

```
d = {
  1: ['a','b'],
  2: ['c','d'],
  8: ['l','p'],
  12: ['u','v','w','x']
}

def getValBeforeAndAfter(d, the_key):
    # convert keys into the list
    d_list = list(sorted(d))
    index = None
    if (the_key in d_list):
        index = d_list.index(the_key)
        try:
            key_before = d_list[index-1]
            key_after = d_list[index+1]
            return str(key_before) + ": " + str(d[key_before]) + "\n" + str(key_after) + ": " + str(d[key_after])
        except: print "Out of range. You are on the edge of the dictionary"        
    else:
        return "No such key in dictionary"

"""
Small test. Expected output: 
1: ['a', 'b']
8: ['l', 'p']
"""
print getValBeforeAndAfter(d, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d2 = {}
d2 = OrderedDict(d2)
d2.update({1: ['a','b']})
d2.update({2: ['c','d']})
d2.update({8: ['l','p']})
d2.update({12: ['u','v','w','x']})

def ajacent(di,key):
    li = list(di.items())
    for i, item in enumerate(li):
        k,v = item
        if k == key and i > 0:
            print(li[i-1])
            print(item)
            print(li[i+1])


print(ajacent(d2,2))

(1, ['a', 'b'])
(2, ['c', 'd'])
(8, ['l', 'p'])
```